# Listing out leap years between certain period

Tags: php

I want to give my students a simple solution 
to view Leap years between 2001-3000.

How Would I write the code for this in PHP?
I'm sure using 'L' but I'm not how to write the code :/

Comment: You're a teacher?  And you can't come up with your own solution to this?  (I could see asking for a *better* solution, but any?)...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for($t = new DateTime("1 Jan 2001"); $t->format('Y') <= 3000; $t->modify('+1 year')) {

    if ($t->format('L')) {
        echo $t->format('Y') ." is a leap year". PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that :

```
<?php
for ($i = 2001; $i <= 3000; $i++)
{
    echo $i;

    if (date('L', strtotime($i . '-01-01')))
    {
        echo ' Yes<br />';
    }
    else
    {
        echo ' No<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to run `date` if you know what a leap year is.

**A leap year is every 4 years, but not every 100 years, then again every 400 years.**

```
for($yr=2000;$yr<=3000;$yr+=4) {
  if( ($yr % 100  == 0) && !($yr % 400 == 0)) continue;
  echo $yr . "<br />";
}
```

Note that I started at the year 2000 since that is a leap year.

Answer (score 1):

```
$years = range(2001,3000);
function is_leap($year) {
    return date_create("$year-01-01")->format('L');
}
$leapYears = array_filter($years, 'is_leap');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 2001; $i <= 3000; $i++) {
    if(date("L", strtotime("01.01.$i")) == 1) echo "$i ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm), here is a PHP version of the algorithm:

```
function is_leap_year($year){
    if( $year % 400 === 0 )
        return true;
    else if( $year % 100 === 0 )
        return false;
    else if( $year % 4 === 0 )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```